# Why does PHP launch interactive console instead of given script?

Tags: php, windows

I have php script running scheduled in Windows Task Scheduler, it always worked ok, but now I get this:

[image]

Task settings:

```
Action: "Launch program"
Program: php
Arguments: "D:\My projects\Exrates\load.php"
```

And everything is ok when I run script manually from cmd.exe:
[image]

What's that?

Windows 10 x64,  PHP 7.2.0b1, "E:\Program Files\PHP 7\" is in my Path.

Comment: You realize that half of your screenshots are unreadable to non-russian speakers?

Comment: I added comment "(These are Program and Parameters fields filled)", other important parts are in English

Comment: Yes, indeed. Didn't notice that comment. It's totally dominated by the images...

Comment: When i need to launch a php script from console i always use this syntax
`php -f "D:\My projects\Exrates\load.php"`
Try to add the -f in argument list

Comment: Nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a PHP 7.2.0b1 bug. Fixed for now in 7.2 branch